# Issues calling mySQL Stored Procedure through Node.JS function

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in my mySQL database from a JavaScript function and get this error consistently when I get to the .query line: "Cannot enqueue Query after invoking quit."

Here's the function that I'm attempting to call:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "8080",
    user: "root",
    password: "pass",
    database: "db"
});

createNewProfile = function (firstName, lastName, type, isActive, securityClearance, location)
{
    var newID;

    var sql = "CALL create_new_profile_id";

    con.connect(function(err)
    {
        if(err) throw(err, "Connection to database for creating new profile failed.");

        con.query(sql, function(err, results)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log(err.message); 
                throw (err, "create_new_profile_id filed.");//this is where the error occurs
            }//if

            newID = results;
        });

        //some more function calls to do other things with the profile
    });//connect

    con.end(function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connection closed.");
    });
}//create new profile
```

The root user has all possible privileges and the sql query works just manually entering it in mysql workbench.

Any thought on this?

Comment: You also might want to consider connection pooling so that the connection is automatically released.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an asyncrhnous function **con.connect** and **con.end** separately. Put your **con.end** inside your **con.query** callback.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "8080",
    user: "root",
    password: "pass",
    database: "db"
});

createNewProfile = function (firstName, lastName, type, isActive, securityClearance, location)
{
    var newID;

    var sql = "CALL create_new_profile_id";

    con.connect(function(err)
    {
        if(err) throw(err, "Connection to database for creating new profile failed.");

        con.query(sql, function(err, results)
        {
            if(err){
                console.log(err.message); 
                throw (err, "create_new_profile_id filed.");//this is where the error occurs
            }//if

            newID = results;
            con.end(function(err){
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log("Connection closed.");
            });
        });
        //some more function calls to do other things with the profile
    });//connect
}//create new profile
```

Comment: I tried that, I'm getting the same error either way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing the con.connect line and just having the con.query.